# Photos missing in both gallery and google photos

Tags: photos

This morning i stupidly formatted my SD card (J2 prime lack of storage issue), and after noticed that photos were missing from both my gallery AND google photos, that were taken over the last few weeks.

After i noticed that my camera was set to store photos on the SD card rather than device. I definitely don't remember putting my camera to store photos on the SD card so not sure what happened there?

Also whenever i delete a photo in gallery it also removes it from google photos.

Will formatting the SD card remove photos from google photos?

I've since taken a photo to make sure it was uploading images so i hope that doesn't mean the images are not recoverable from the device?

I'm only using the phone on 4g.

Any ideas on getting the photos back?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting your SD card shall not delete the synced items from your Google photos account.

Google photos app also shows your offline photos. So, unless they were uploaded to the cloud drive, they are now gone and cannot be recovered.

Please check once by logging into your account at [photos.google.com](https://photos.google.com/). If your photos appear there, then they are in the cloud and you can safely get them back on your device.